# SQL. Limited query

Tags: sql

I have a view and I request data from it with a simple query like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE id IN (...)
```

In general on "normal data" it should return 10-100 entries per id, but for some ids, it may return more than 1,000,000 entries!

I would like to limit my query so that it would not return more than 100 entries per id, but I really have no idea other than running a query for each id separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select v.*
from (select v.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from my_view
      where id in (...)
     ) v
where seqnum <= 100;
```

Comment: Yes, but that would limit all query result to 100 entrys, right? For example if I query with ids 1, 2, 3 and there are 40, 60 and 2000 entrys per id, I would like to get all entrys for ids 1 and 2 and 100 entrys for id 3

Comment: That is exactly the query given by Mr.Linoff does. seqnum derived by using analytical function and it holds the row_number initialized per id and then in the outer query it restricts to <=100. another suggestion would be , to avoid order by overhead you can just use count(*) instead row_number.

Comment: @Letanir Yes, each "id subset" gets limited to 100 rows.